# Manual t-test in R, Tail test

Tags: r, p-value, significance

I've been trying to make a manual t test of a statistic that I calculated in r. I've seen some people recommend to use the function dt but that had not worked. I know because I'm comparing my results of R with my results in STATA (the last ones I'm sure I've got them correct). This is the code with which I'm trying to do this

```
pvalue<-dt(3.141523, df=8)
```

Where 3.141523 is my calculated t statistic and df is degrees of freedom. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should include some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What exactly is the test you ran in STATA? Was it one-sided? two-sided? paired? What did your data look like? How different are the two values you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `pt()` function instead of `dt()`. `dt()` is the density while `pt()` is the distribution.

```
> pt(3.141523, df = 8)
[1] 0.9931132
```

Comment: If it's a p-value it could happen that the OP wants or needs `lower.tail = FALSE`, but it's really impossible to know.